# Multiple Result Sets in Oracle Anonymous Block

Tags: oracle, toad

Are there any Oracle tools that will output multiple result sets from an anonymous block?

In Sql Server I frequently run sets of statements similar to the following...

```
DECLARE @MostRecentPurchaseOrderId int;
SELECT @MostRecentPurchaseOrderId = MAX(PurchaseOrderId) FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders;
SELECT * FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders WHERE PurchaseOrderId = @MostRecentPurchaseOrderId;
SELECT * FROM dbo.PurchaseOrderDetails WHERE PurchaseOrderId = @MostRecentPurchaseOrderId;
```

I run some freshly-written c# then run these sql statements in ssms to have a look at the data I just wrote.

But in Oracle, everything is different.
If I just wanted to run two sql statements, most tools will allow that.
But if I want to declare a variable, select a value into it, then use the value of that variable in one or more select statements, I have to use an anonymous block. And you can't just have a stand-alone SELECT statement in an anonymous block. Here is what I have to do.

```
DECLARE purchaseOrderId NUMBER(16);
        TYPE RefCursor IS REF CURSOR;
        purchaseOrders RefCursor;
        purchaseOrderDetails RefCursor;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(PurchaseOrderId) INTO purchaseOrderId FROM PurchaseOrders;

    OPEN purchaseOrders FOR
        SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = purchaseOrderId;

    OPEN purchaseOrderDetails FOR
        SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrderDetails WHERE PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = purchaseOrderId;
END;
```

The question is how to display the results of the two ref cursors in a grid.

In TOAD, if I add a couple of undeclared variables
(:purchaseOrdersOutput and :purchaseOrderDetailsOutput) it gets me almost there but not all the way. When I run it TOAD will display a dialog asking me to select the type of the two variables, I select Cursor and TOAD will execute and load the content of the first ref cursor into the data grid. But there is no output shown from the second cursor.

```
DECLARE purchaseOrderId NUMBER(16);
        TYPE RefCursor IS REF CURSOR;
        purchaseOrders RefCursor;
        purchaseOrderDetails RefCursor;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(PurchaseOrderId) INTO purchaseOrderId FROM PurchaseOrders;

    OPEN purchaseOrders FOR
        SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = purchaseOrderId;
    :purchaseOrdersOutput := purchaseOrders;

    OPEN purchaseOrderDetails FOR
        SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrderDetails WHERE PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = purchaseOrderId;
    :purchaseOrderDetailsOutput := purchaseOrderDetails;
END;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? Also: I don't use TOAD, but most SQL clients allow you to define variables that are managed by the SQL tool, not the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand from your requirement,
you need to get the data sets of `purchaseOrderDetails` and `PurchaseOrders` filtered by the Maximum `PurchaseOrderId`, then display them together in a Grid-Like View.

You can't directly display results of a cursor in a PL/SQL block. 
Unlike SQL, PL/SQL is not designed to directly show results of a query in the IDE.

What you can do is to just outright write a SQL Statement using the below query and execute:

```
SELECT  po.* 
    ,   pod.*
FROM    PurchaseOrders po
    ,   PurchaseOrderDetails pod
WHERE   po.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = pod.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID
and     po.PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = (SELECT  MAX(PurchaseOrderId) 
                                from    PurchaseOrders);
```

This requires no PL/SQL, only pure SQL and addresses your requirement (assuming i understood your requirement correctly).

One more approach you can take is to place the results of your query into variables and display them on the terminal using `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was really trying to avoid the MAX() call twice -solely for purist reasons :) -but you are right, from everything I have seen this is the only option. And it absolutely produces the end result I am looking for, 2 grids. Thanks for breaking me out of my tunnel vision!